# Django premailer - Removes responsiveness from email template

Tags: css, django, premailer

I am trying to send an email using Django. The email template was made by someone else with a ton of CSS and it will take a lot of hours just to "inline" it. So I used premailer to inline the CSS automatically. It worked pretty well till I saw that it also inlined the media queries that were responsible for the responsiveness of the templates.

One solution I saw was to put media queries in a separate style tag and put

```
data-premailer="ignore"
```

but unfortunately, I think this solution does not work anymore.

I also tried using django_inlinecss, but that didn't work for me also.
Please let me know how to fix premailer or if there any other package available that can inline CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @ahsan mukhtar you don't have to use any external library use django `EmailMessage`

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from domain_project import settings
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import JsonResponse
from contact.models import Contact

def contact(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        contact = Contact()
        contact.name = request.GET.get('name')
        contact.email = request.GET.get('email')
        contact.phone = request.GET.get('phone')
        contact.subject = request.GET.get('subject')
        contact.message = request.GET.get('message')
        contact.save()
        ctx = {
        'name': request.GET['name'],
        'email': request.GET['email'],
        'phone': request.GET['phone'],
        'message':request.GET['message']
        }
        email_temp = get_template('email_template/contact_email.html').render(ctx)
        msg = EmailMessage(
            'Hello'+' '+str(request.GET['name']),
            email_temp,
            settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
            [request.GET.get('email'),],
            )
        msg.content_subtype = "html"
        msg.send()
      return JsonResponse({'massage':"massage"},safe=True)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <style type="text/css">
        @media screen {
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Lato';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/qIIYRU-oROkIk8vfvxw6QvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff) format('woff');
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Lato';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 700;
                src: local('Lato Bold'), local('Lato-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/qdgUG4U09HnJwhYI-uK18wLUuEpTyoUstqEm5AMlJo4.woff) format('woff');
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Lato';
                font-style: italic;
                font-weight: 400;
                src: local('Lato Italic'), local('Lato-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/RYyZNoeFgb0l7W3Vu1aSWOvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff) format('woff');
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Lato';
                font-style: italic;
                font-weight: 700;
                src: local('Lato Bold Italic'), local('Lato-BoldItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/HkF_qI1x_noxlxhrhMQYELO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff) format('woff');
            }
        }

        /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
        body,
        table,
        td,
        a {
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
        }

        img {
            -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        }

        /* RESET STYLES */
        img {
            border: 0;
            height: auto;
            line-height: 100%;
            outline: none;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
        }

        body {
            height: 100% !important;
            margin: 0 !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
        a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            font-size: inherit !important;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-weight: inherit !important;
            line-height: inherit !important;
        }

        /* MOBILE STYLES */
        @media screen and (max-width:600px) {
            h1 {
                font-size: 32px !important;
                line-height: 32px !important;
            }
        }

        /* ANDROID CENTER FIX */
        div[style*="margin: 16px 0;"] {
            margin: 0 !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #f4f4f4; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;">
    <!-- HIDDEN PREHEADER TEXT -->
    <div
        style="display: none; font-size: 1px; color: #fefefe; line-height: 1px; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    </div>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <!-- LOGO -->
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ed3936" align="center">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 40px 10px 40px 10px;"> </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ed3936" align="center" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <!-- name,email,phone,looking_for,message -->
                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" valign="top"
                            style="padding: 40px 20px 20px 20px; border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px; color: #111111; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 48px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 4px; line-height: 48px;">
                            <h1 style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: 400; margin: 1;">Welcome!&nbsp;<br>
                                <span style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 500;">{{ name }}</span></h1>
                            <img src="https://media.itdude.in/media/email_template.png" width="125" height="120"
                                style="display: block; border: 0px;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" align="center" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"
                            style="padding: 20px 30px 40px 30px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;">
                            <h4 style="margin-bottom: 0;">Your Requrement :</h4>
                            <p style="margin: 0;">{{ message }}<br></p>
                            <p style="color:black;">You will receive a call frome us within 2 working days.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"
                            style="padding: 20px 30px 40px 30px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;">
                            <p style="margin-bottom: -50px; color:black; text-align:center;">We're excited to have you
                                get started. Explore our Website. Just press the button below.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 20px 30px 60px 30px;">
                                        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" style="border-radius: 3px;" bgcolor="#ed3936"><a
                                                        href="https://domain.in/" target="_blank"
                                                        style="font-size: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding: 15px 25px; border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid #ed3936; display: inline-block; ">Explore
                                                        Our Website</a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr> <!-- COPY -->
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"
                            style="padding: 0px 30px 20px 30px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;">
                            <p style="margin: 0;">If you have any questions, just reply to this email—we're always happy
                                to help out.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"
                            style="padding: 0px 30px 40px 30px; border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;">
                            <p style="margin: 0; color:red;">Domain</p>
                            <small style="color:black;">TECH SOLUTIONS PVT. LTD.</small><br>
                            <small>
                                <b>Phone:</b>
                                <a href="tel:+91 9999999999" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">
                                    +91 9999999999
                                </a><br>
                                <b>Email:</b>
                                <a href="mailto:contact@domain.in" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">
                                    contact@domain.in
                                </a></small>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" align="center" style="padding: 30px 10px 0px 10px;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#FFECD1" align="center"
                            style="padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;">
                            <h2 style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 400; color: #111111; margin: 0;">Need more help?
                            </h2>
                            <p style="margin: 0;"><a href="https://domain.in/contact/" target="_blank"
                                    style="color: #5762cc;">We&rsquo;re here to help you out</a></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>

</html>
```